# Animate UILabel width with fixed center

Tags: swift, uiview, uilabel, uianimation

How to animate a change in width while keeping the view centered?

Currently when I do it, it doesn't grow from the center.

```
self.textLabel = UILabel()
self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, Globals.voterTextLabel, Globals.voterTextLabel)
self.textLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)
self.textLabel.text = "VS"
self.textLabel.layer.cornerRadius = Globals.voterTextLabel/2
self.textLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
self.textLabel.clipsToBounds = true
self.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.textLabel.textColor = Colors.voterTextLabel
self.textLabel.textAlignment = .Center
self.textLabel.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth
self.view.addSubview(self.textLabel) 

 UIView.animateWithDuration(2, animations: {
    self.textLabel.frame.size.width = 150
    self.textLabel.center.x = self.view.frame.width/2
 }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you.
You just need to give scale for width and height (default 1, which will have no effect). And this will animate your view's frame.

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.textLabel.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 1);
    }, completion: nil)
```

And if you don't want to stretch the content, than you may try this:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

        var newWidth:CGFloat = 200.0;

        var oldWidth:CGFloat = self.textLabel.frame.width;

        var totalChangeWidth:CGFloat = newWidth - oldWidth;

        var newHeight:CGFloat = 200.0;

        var oldHeight:CGFloat = self.textLabel.frame.width;

        var totalChangeHeight:CGFloat = newHeight - oldHeight;

        self.textLabel.bounds.size = CGSizeMake(self.textLabel.frame.size.width + totalChangeWidth, self.textLabel.frame.size.height + totalChangeHeight);

        self.textLabel.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/2)

    }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: @EricD. Sorry for objective-c code. Updated my answer with Swift code snippet.

Comment: Thanks @EricD. I dont wan't to stretch the contents, specially if I have text inside. Is there a way to actually change the width?

Comment: @bvallelunga Hope this may help you, now. :)

Comment: @bvallelunga If it is appropriate, then please accept this as answer. It'll help  others to choose the best one.

Comment: But you can't assign something to a part of a struct in Obj C. Assigning to `size` will give you an error.  How do you do this then in Obj C?